# Increment struct value in Go

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm, go-fiber

I'm expecting to see the `visits` increment with every `GET` request to `/foo` but it remains as `1`. What am I doing wrong here?

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

// Item model
type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    UID    int64  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement"`
    Name   string `gorm:"index;not null"`
    Visits int32  `gorm:"default 0"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Item{})
    db.Create(&Item{
        Name: "foo",
    })

    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{})

    app.Get("/:name", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        var i Item
        db.First(&i, "name = ?", c.Params("name"))

        if i.Name == "" {
            return c.Status(fiber.StatusNotFound).JSON(&fiber.Map{
                "message": "Not found",
            })
        }

        db.Model(&i).Update("visits", i.Visits+1)
        return c.JSON(i)
    })

    log.Println("Listening...")
    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":3000"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log the error like:

```golang
if err := db.Model(&i).Update("visits", i.Visits+1).Error; err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("update err != nil; %v\n", err)
}
```

You will see that it says: "WHERE conditions required". So, you can fix this like:

```golang
if err := db.Model(&i).Where("name = ?", i.Name).Update("visits", i.Visits+1).Error; err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("update err != nil; %v\n", err)
}
```

Here is some more details about [Error Handling in GORM](https://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html)

---

EDIT: There is actually a larger issue at play here with your example. The issue is that you are defining `UID` as part of your `Item` model which conflicts with what `gorm.Model` provides. You can see in [Declaring Models](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html) the following model definition:

```golang
// gorm.Model definition
type Model struct {
  ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

which when added to your `Item` type / model, you would get:

```golang
type Item struct {
  // gorm.Model
  ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
  // your fields
  UID    int64  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement"`
  Name   string `gorm:"index;not null"`
  Visits int32  `gorm:"default 0"`
}
```

It seems like this results in your database table being created in a weird state. You might notice in your returned JSON payload that both the `ID` AND `UID` are equal to 0. And as you start/stop the server multiple times and look at the additional records that are created (because of your `db.Create()` at the top) you end up with multiple Items with a name of "foo" all of which having `ID` and `UID` of 0... this is why GORM is then unable to update the item without a WHERE clause, since the primary keys are not properly set on the table.

If you remove UID from your model (or maybe even just remove "primaryKey" from it) you can then use the `Update()` method without the need for the where condition. So, your model should look like:

```
// Item model
type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name   string `gorm:"index;not null"`
    Visits int32  `gorm:"default 0"`
}
```

After you make changes to your model / type, make sure to delete your `test.db` file in order to have the table re-created with the new / correct format.

---

Lastly, in regards to my original answer, you should also see the errors being logged to your console automatically by GORM without needing to specifically handle them like I suggested.

Comment: I'd followed the examples from the doc https://gorm.io/docs/#Quick-Start - thank you!

Comment: Oh, interesting! After going over their quick start guide, that led me to thinking there might actually be something else at play... see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation, things make more sense now :-)